# Fetch or Get from system?

Tags: word-choice

Which is more correct use of the words? And what sounds better to a native English speaking person?

- **Fetch** from system?
- **Get** from system?

The context is setting the locale in a web application.

EDIT: The information is retrieved from the browsers API which gets the information from the operating system. So technically it should be *Get* in my opinion but I was thinking from an end user perspective.

Comment: What is the context of the application's action? To me, _fetch_ implies a round trip (request for data and receiving data) while _get_ just says the application receives from the system (which may or may not be the result of a request).

Comment: This is entirely context-dependent. What is correct for one protocol or programming language might be incorrect for another.

Comment: @nick012000, it's in the UI so the end user will not know about the protocol or programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fetch* and *get* are both transitive verbs. They require an object noun phrase.

- *He fetched **the butter** from the pantry.*
- *She got **a letter from her brother** today.*

Without the object, they're ungrammatical.

- **He fetched  from the pantry.*
- **She got today.*

They don't mean the same thing, either.  *Fetch* has a very specific meaning:

- go somewhere else, pick up something, and return with it

*Get*, on the other hand, has many different meanings, though only the one meaning 'come to have' (or 'cause to have') is involved here.

The OQ doesn't provide sufficient context for an answer -- just for starts, **what** is to be fetched or gotten, for what purpose, from where, and by what means? -- but I would suggest that a complete sentence is more informative than a verb phrase with an imaginary object.  It is never wise to believe that your readers have exactly the same imagination you do.

And I wouldn't recommend either *fetch* **or** *get*, either. One is rare and dialectal, the other is overly common and multiply ambiguous; and they're both ungrammatical without objects.

Comment: I'm thinking implicitly that the application is the noun. And your examples are in past tense. I looked up the definition and I think it's easier to apply in real world examples than digital examples. Personally I think *Get* sounds and logically is more correct. But I wanted a second opinion. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. I would use fetch because it sounds nicer, but you could also base it on what it exactly is called you are doing.

For example, get would be logical if you were dealing with a GET request.

And who do you mean by native? Anyone? I'm not a native myself but depending on who from where you ask, you might get different answers.

Comment: Native; someone who grew up talking the language in a country where English is the primary language.

I thought the technical aspect should not be to important as its the end user who will se the text on a button.